# maintain a log of SQL server database changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

if we are changing database time to time,

```
            ex: adding columns,new tables,adding stored procedures etc.
```

how we can track or maintain a log of those changes?

Comment: Use a database project to maintain your changes and put that project under source control.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i will try that way. if there more suggestion please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try creating a Database Trigger to track the changes made to the objects.